# Cannot send arbitrarily long messages via sockets

Tags: sockets, networking, rust

I'm writing a traceroute implementation and I'm deliberately trying to send a long message for the purposes of path maximum transmission unit detection. However, when I try to send something longer than 1500 bytes, I get:

```
thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 90, kind: Uncategorized, message: "Message too long" }', src/main.rs:115:26
```

I'm expecting to see a Fragmentation needed ICMP message.

The socket comes from the [raw-socket](https://lib.rs/crates/raw-socket) crate.

It seems that PMTU is hard-coded somewhere deep. Or am I misdiagnosing this? What would prevent me from sending arbitrarily long messages via sockets?

MCVE:

```
use raw_socket::{RawSocket, Domain, Protocol, Type};
use raw_socket::option::{Level, Name};
use raw_socket::ffi::c_int;

fn main() {
    let sock = RawSocket::new(Domain::ipv4(), Type::raw(), Protocol::from(255).into()).unwrap();
    let buf = [0u8; 9000];
    const IP_MTU_DISCOVER: i32 = 10;
    const IP_PMTU_DISC_PROBE: i32 = 3;
    
    sock.set_sockopt(Level::IPV4, Name::from(IP_MTU_DISCOVER), &(IP_PMTU_DISC_PROBE as c_int))
        .unwrap();
    
    sock.send_to(&buf, "142.250.201.206:33434").unwrap();
}
```

Comment: You are exceeding the MTU of your local connection. Start with a message the size of your local MTU. Your own host does not send an ICMP message back.

Comment: @RonMaupin well then I'm just prolonging getting an error to a host a bit farther.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy perhaps you want to elaborate. I'm sending a buffer full of random bytes using `send_to`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy as I said, the socket is an IPv4 raw socket, speaking IPPROTO_RAW. From my understanding, I need to feed it an IP packet, and framing happens on the link layer below, and as I understand, it happens automatically without the programmer's assist.

Comment: I think the above comment is the first time you said explicitly which kind of raw socket you were using.

Comment: Sorry, I agree that I should've been more explicit.

Comment: This is trickier than I expected. Please accept my apologies for not giving you enough credit early on.